# Dataframe[-list,] two commas meaning

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

```
unwanted <- which((Tdata$V1 == "someString"))

if(length(unwanted)>0){
  Tdata <- Tdata[-unwanted,]   
}
```

I do not get this part **Tdata[-unwanted,]**. What does the dash mean? Whats the significance of leaving the second entry after the comma empty?

I would appreciate any references to tutorials or any answer to my question.

Comment: the ```-``` implies that the selected row is being removed from the dataframe and the ```,``` implies that all the columns of that particular row are being dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.frame`, `matrix`, the indexing is `row, column` the index can be either column names or logical vector or numeric index.  Here, we have a numeric index from `which`.  The `-` on the numeric index make sure that rows are removed.   The significance of leaving the column index empty is to select all columns

With a  small reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars[-1, ] # removes the first row

mtcars[-c(1, 3, 5),] # removes the first, third and fifth row

mtcars[-c(1, 3, 5), c(1,2)] # removes the first, third, fifth rows, select 1st and 2nd column
```